# Laravel in subdirectory returning 404 - Not Found

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I tried to install Laravel in subdirectory in Docker. Although the root domain is working fine, the laravel installation in subdirectory giving 404 - Not Found. Here is the nginx config file. I guess I didn't set up the nginx perfectly. I appreciate if you can help. Thanks.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 120M;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    }
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
    
    location /laravel {
        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /laravel/public/index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

[image: error image]

Comment: So you probably went to http://localhost/laravel/public and got a 404 error? Then check your routes file first. Also check nginx error log. Consider just making a new virtualhost, so 'laravel.local' in your `/etc/hosts` file points to `127.0.0.1` and then add an extra .conf file, just for your `laravel.local` hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it. Here is the .conf file.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    client_max_body_size 120M;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    }

    location /api {
        alias /var/www/api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        }
    }

    location @api {
        rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}
```